# Which wide-angle lens for Nikon?

Tags: lens, nikon, wide-angle

I have a Nikon D70 and my better half has a Nikon D3000. She uses a 18-55mm lens (I think) and I have a Nikon 18-200mm lens which I love.

We are going to Peru next year and I would like to get a wide-angle lens for our trip as I think there could be some amazing photo opportunities.

We both enjoy photography but we don't take enough to justify anything more than £300ish ($500). However, we could possibly stretch our budget slightly if required.

Are there any wide angle lens's that anyone could recommend?

Comment: Are you looking for something wider than 18mm, which already falls into the category of "wide angle," or something in the same neighborhood that's faster or produces better images?

Comment: [Wide angle lenses tend to be expensive](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4487/why-are-wide-angle-lenses-so-much-more-expensive), so with a moderate budget you could also consider renting one just for the trip.

Comment: Imre, thanks for your suggestion, we'll take a look at renting a wide angle lens for the trip.

Comment: Blrfl - something wider than 18mm preferably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that budget *per-person*? If so, the lens to get is the [Nikkor 12-24mm F/4](http://www.neocamera.com/lens/nikkor/af-s_dx_12-24mm_f4g_if-ed). It has very good image quality and remains quite sharp even wide-open. Goes for around $1000.

If you do not mind one that will autofocus on the D70 but *not* on the D3000, then you should really get the [Tokina 11-16mm F/2.8](http://www.neocamera.com/lens/tokina/at-x_116_pro_dx/nikon). Its image quality is amazing and is one full stop brighter than the Nikon. On the D3000 is has to be focused manually. It goes for around $600. *Do not confuse it with the II version which costs $150 more and does autofocus on the D3000.*

There is also a [Tokina 12-24mm F/4](http://www.neocamera.com/lens/tokina/at-x_124_af_pro_dx_ii/nikon) which is good too and falls just at $499 USD. It will autofocus on both your cameras.

*Feel free to look for any of these lenses used if you want to save some cash.*

Comment: Itai, thanks for your reply which is very helpful. The budget is probably around $500 for the lens total although we would probably stretch to $600 or $750 for the Tokina. Will take a look at all your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Itai for the advice on both lenses.  I have a D3000 and recently acquired a D70 because I've had an AF-50mm f/1.8 that doesn't auto-focus on the D3000 due to the absence of the AF body motor and I wanted to use it with auto-focus.  I'll check out your links.